# How do i properly rescale an image on PyGame without it being badly cropped?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to rescale an image on pygame but it instead crops the image, I'm just looking to change the pixel width and height of the image.

I used `pygame.transform.scale` and used 1900, 600 as the parameters, the original image is a 1920x1080

```
mainmenu = pygame.image.load("Main_Menu.png")
mainmenu = pygame.transform.scale(mainmenu, (1900,600))
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

I expected the image to be rescaled to a 1900x600 image but it instead output a badly cropped image in the 1900x600 format.

Answer (score 4):

You've to use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) rather than [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale).
Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) to convert the surface to a surface with a with proper pixel format

```py
mainmenu = pygame.image.load("Main_Menu.png")
mainmenu = pygame.transform.smoothscale(mainmenu.convert_alpha(), (1900,600)) 
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

While `scale()` does a scaling operation, which is as fast as possible, `smoothscale()` scales smoothly and calculates area averages of the colors which cover the pixels.

Comment: I end up getting an error, this is what the Python shell spat out:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    mainmenu = pygame.transform.smoothscale(mainmenu, (1900,600))
ValueError: Only 24-bit or 32-bit surfaces can be smoothly scaled

Comment: @TheForeigner Use `.convert()` or `.convert_alpha()`